# How do I fix vertical spacing between tables?

Tags: tables, spacing

I have a document with about 50 tables in it.  If one of the tables goes over the page, LaTeX automatically sends that table to the next page.  The issue is that LaTeX increases the spacing between the remaining tables on the first page, which is not what I desire.  How do I maintain a fixed vertical space between tables rather than having the spacing increase?

Example code:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}
 ...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

(this repeats multiple times)

Desired output: multiple tables on some pages with equal spacing between end of one table and start of the next constant (unless next table starts on new page).

Comment: If you have  several picture per line, perhaps you should take a look at the `floatrow` package.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give many clues but I would guess that you have `\flushbottom` in effect and a setting of `\floatsep` such as the default of `12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt`

So either you need `\raggedbottom` so latex doesn't try to stretch out each page, or you could try setting

```
\setlength\floatsep {12pt}
```

so the inter-float separation was not flexible, although unless there is some other stretch space on the page this will lead to under full pages if `\flushbottom` is in use.

If you have 50 tables with no intervening text, you probably should just set them directly as minipages rather than use the float mechanism, which isn't really designed for that use case.

Comment: \raggedbottom still has the same issue.  I tried using minipages, but minipages give \hbox too wide errors.

Comment: @Arlington as I say you have given no hint as to your input or output so people can only guess. Perhaps your tables are on float pages not text pages in which case you need to set `\@fpsep` not `\floatsep`

Comment: @Arlington `minipages` will not give overfull hbox errors if you do not make them too wide: again if you do not show code, we can not guess what is wrong with the code, although actually I'd guess that you neglected paragraph indentation and could put `\centering` before them to avoid that.

Comment: Have updated with code.

Comment: @Arlington: Why does `\raggedbottom` not work? What about issuing it just after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: @Arlington No. sorry that code fragment isn't at all useful in debugging your problem

Comment: That code fragment is literally the sum of my entire document; after \begin{document}, that code fragment is basically repeated with data inside the tables.  Nonetheless, I've managed to get minipages to work (though I'm not sure why they started working now).